# Smarty: get the current physical file path

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

In Smarty, is there a way to retrieve the current physical path of the template file?

I'm looking for the Smarty equivalent of the PHP `__FILE__` super-variable.

(I'm sure that this question must have been asked before, but I can't for the life of me find it.  Or maybe there's a good reason it hasn't been asked!?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [`{$smarty}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl) reserved variable.

- You can get constants, using [`{$smarty.const.CONST_NAME}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#language.variables.smarty.const), but that will give you the compiled file's path in the case of `__FILE__`
- You can get separate the directory & the file, using [`{$smarty.current_dir}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#language.variables.smarty.current_dir) & [`{$smarty.template}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#language.variables.smarty.template)

Comment: Yes, `{$smarty.current_dir}` and `{$smarty.template}` are the variables I was looking for.  Not sure why that was so difficult to find on the google searches.  Thanks.